# PHP PDO в чем разница ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false и true

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Пробовал вставлять значения разных типов данных в колонки с разными типами данных при ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false и true, разницы не увидел, может кто объяснить в чем отличие?

```
//типы колонов r1 = int, r2 = varchar, r3 = bool

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charser=utf8', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$smt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO pwnd (r1, r2 ,r3) VALUES (:r1, :r2, :r3)');
echo $smt->execute([':r1' => 'a2', ':r3' => 'false', ':r2' => true]);
```

Comment: видимой разницы и не должно быть, разница по большому счету только в том, на чьей стороне будет собираться запрос - на стороне pdo или mysql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

С `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` в значении `true` за обработку подготовленных выражений отвечает сам PDO. В базу данных передаётся чистый запрос с уже подставленными и корректно экранированными данными (только в `dsn` не забывайте правильно `charset` указывать).

`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` в значении `false` именно использует штатный механизм СУБД для подготовки запроса и затем отдельным обращением передаёт данные для этого запроса. Т.е. нормальные, реальные подготовленные выражения.

Из не очевидных моментов:

- для сложных запросов дико удобно использовать именованные параметры несколько раз. Какой-нибудь `where user_from = :id or user_to = :id` и передать только один id. Такое возможно только с эмуляцией запросов.
- специфика конкретных СУБД. Какие-то СУБД из тех, что умеет PDO могут не уметь подготовленные выражения. Например, очень популярный `PgBouncer` (пул коннектов для `PostgreSQL`) не умеет обрабатывать подготовленные выражения. С эмуляцией выражений можно в коде проекта пользоваться удобствами API с prepare
- вопрос с тем, что подготовленный запрос разбирается и строит план один раз и затем только выполняется - на самом деле гораздо сложнее. Тот же `mysql` сохраняет запрос только в рамках соединения. Поэтому в типичном сценарии использования "подготовил, выполнил, закрыл соединение" никаких плюсов реальное препарирование не даёт. А кэширование плана между соединениями - по-моему (сам с этой СУБД не работал), есть в `Oracle` и приносит некоторое количество головной боли, ведь оптимальный план запроса в немалой степени зависит от самих данных.

Comment: `С PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES в значении true за обработку подготовленных выражений отвечает сам PDO. В базу данных передаётся чистый запрос с уже подставленными и корректно экранированными данными` исходя из этих строк, я так понимаю, что при значении `false` bindParam PDO::PARAM_INT не срабатывает? А используется сама СУБД?

Comment: По идее срабатывает и на уровне протокола значение отправляется уже в виде числа, а не строки. Но здесь не уверен и, возможно даже, специфично для каждого драйвера СУБД в отдельности.

Answer (score 1):

Отличие в том, что к *типам* подставляемых переменных режим эмуляции не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

За тип привязываемой переменной отвечает третий параметр в `bindParam`/`bindValue`. В то время как для всех передаваемых в execute() переменных по умолчанию используется тип "строка".

Поэтому ставить ставить вопрос про связь типов и режима эмуляции попросту некорректно - эти понятия никак между собой не связаны.