# Разница подготовки запроса prepare

Tags: php

У меня был такой код

```
$idQuest = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($questionId)));
$setRename = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($name)));
$sql = "UPDATE question SET `user_name` = '".$setRename."' WHERE id = '".$idQuest."'";
$setName = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$setName->execute();
```

Мне рекомендовали, переделать его, с применением bindValue

и я сделал так

```
$idQuest = $questionId;
$setRename = $name;
$sth = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE question SET `user_name` = :setRename WHERE id = :idQuest");
$sth->bindValue(':setRename', $setRename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':idQuest', $idQuest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Чем же он лучше?

Comment: За такое `trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags()))` сразу можно увольнять :) Особенно для ID!!!

Comment: 1-й вариант бесмысленный. Зачем `prepare` если запрос полный. Что нужно экранировать? Во втором случаэ db/driver сами всё правильно экранируют.

Comment: то есть первый вариант, prepare можно заменить на query и будет то же самое?

Comment: @DivMan Да, только с `SQL Injection` дыркой.

Comment: А что бы не было дырки, что надо сделать?

Comment: @DivMan, использовать второй вариант из вашего вопроса. Еще сюда зайдите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083