# Отправка HTML кода из Textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Итак. Есть некий скрипт, часть из которого приведена ниже, который отправляет HTML код из поля `<textarea>`:

```
function editothers(id, fn, fv) {
    $('textarea[name=other' + fn + ']').removeClass('success').addClass('inprocess');
    console.log('textarea[name=other' + fn + ']');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/php/other_shop/edit_other_shop.php',
        data: {
            item_id: id,
            o_field_id: fn,
            o_field_value: fv
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                getothers(id);
                setTimeout('classes('+fn+')', 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Далее - PHP:

```
<?php
//admin
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

include_once('db.php');
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
$o_field_id = 'o_field_'.$_POST['o_field_id'];
$o_field_value = $_POST['o_field_value'];

    echo $o_field_id;
    if ( isset($_POST['item_id']) )
    {

            try{
                    $st_check_double = $db->query("SELECT item_id FROM other_shop1 WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'");
                    $resultscheck_double = $st_check_double->fetch();
                    if (!$resultscheck_double){
                        $db->exec("INSERT INTO other_shop1  

                        ('$o_field_id', item_id)

                                             VALUES 

                        ( '$o_field_value' ,  '$item_id' )

                                             ");
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-info">Код был только что добавлен</div>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $db->exec("UPDATE other_shop1  

                                            SET

                        '$o_field_id'='$o_field_value'


                                            WHERE

                        item_id='$item_id'

                                             ");                        
                    }
                }
                catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                    echo "Ошибка проверки дублей";
                }

    }

?>
```

**Вопрос первый.** Все данные отправляются, однако возле кавычек появляется обратный слеш (**\"**). Для чего происходит экранирование спец.символов в JS я знаю, а вот можно ли этого избежать на этапе отправки в конкретном примере? К слову, править php.ini или .htacces возможности нет.

**Вопрос второй.** Если все же избежать нельзя, то можно ли при выдаче данных пройтись по всему содержимому и убрать лишний символ, например, через `.replace`? Вот участки отвечающие за вывод данных:

```
function getothers(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/php/other_shop/show_other_shop.php',
        data: {
            item_id: id
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                var arr = new Array;
                var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                for (var i = 40; i >= 10; i--) {
                    if ( arr['o_field_' + i] != null && arr['o_field_' + i] != '' )
                    $('#others'+i).html(arr['o_field_' + i]).parent().show();
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

и php

```
<?php
//frontend
include_once('db.php');
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
try
            {
                $st2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM other_shop1 WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'");
                $results2 = $st2->fetchAll();
                if ($results2)
                            {
                                foreach ($results2 as $row2)
                                {
                                  //echo "<pre>";
                                      echo json_encode($row2);
                                  //echo "</pre>";
                                }
                            }

            }
        catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
                echo "Ошибка.";
            }

?>
```

Если нужно добавить больше данных - сделаем. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Зачем вам PDO, если вы его криво используете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083 и http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#prepared Только подготовленные выражения, а не вставка пришедших данных прямо в запросы!

Comment: @Visman Спасибо большое за наводку. Некоторые изменения я все же внес, но с экранированием так и не разобрался. Если у вас будут мысли на этот счет, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev можете дать пример экранированной строки?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan если поставить кавычки, то добавляется обратный слеш, а если одинарные кавычки, то отправка вообще не происходит. В целом, хочу отправлять html код, а не обычный текст. Возможно реализация не самая лучшая для этой задачи, переделывал из примера, а познаний на все не хватает.

Comment: Как удалить экранирования  ? `function stripslashes(str){
 return str.replace('/\0/g', '0').replace('/\(.)/g', '$1');
}

alert(stripslashes('Eto Mike O\'Brian tip takoy \:\)'));
`

Comment: Если не подойдет тогда объясните каким образом вы экранируете   спец символы ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что данный вопрос необходимо решить все же во время отправки данных. Из вашего сообщения следует, что данные отправляются, а затем возвращаются с обратным слешем. Скорее всего ваш сервер раздает _GET и _POST массивам эти самые слэши возле кавычек.

Если вы знаете, что такое экранирование, следовательно уже изучали возможности отключения. Если так, то я все же повторюсь, при отсутствии возможности редактирования .htacces или php.ini, вы можете выполнить отключение этих волшебных кавычек прямо в скрипте. Вот первый попавшийся пример из сети:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

Однако, далеко не всегда это может помочь. В этом случае, можно перейти к плану "Б". Использовать костыль. Воткну его в ваш пример, а вы уж потестируйте и сообщите, помогло ли это решению вашей задачи.

Весь участок копировать не буду, думаю, знаете где он находится:

`$o_field_value = $_POST['o_field_value'];` меняем на `$o_field_value = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($_POST['o_field_value']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');`

Не забывайте, что отключение экранирования может негативно сказаться на безопасности и работоспособности сайта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Первый вариант я видел в сети и пробовал применить. А вот второй вечером опробую и отпишусь по результату.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам снова. Я несколько дней промучился с этим делом. Бегло проверил, работоспособность и все в норме. Завтра поподробнее все пересмотрю и отмечу ваш ответ, если все будет хорошо) Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Все работает как надо. Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 4):

Вообще то я не могу понять чем они вам мешают. Это делается автоматическим образом для того что бы избежать `SQL` инъекций. А если у вас в фронте строка экранированная то если его сунуть куда то в код `HTML` все ровно экранирование убирается браузером. А вот и пример, если я что то не так понял то скажите?

Это моя строка который я добавляю в `textarea`:

```
let str = '\"My name is Vsya\", My name is Petya\",....';
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let str = '\"My name is Vsya\", My name is Petya\",....';
    $('#mytextarea').text(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

А вот второй вариант который вы сказали, принудительно убрать экранирование прежде чем вывести контент на страницу. Для этого воспользуемся методом `replase`:

Вот второй пример кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let str_spec = '<dl><dt>$$<\/dt><dd>\"Вставляет \"$\"</dd><dt>$&amp;<\/dt><dd>Вставляет \"совпавшую подстроку<\/dd><dt>$\`<\/dt><dd>Вставляет часть строки, которая предшествует совпавшей подстроке</dd><dt>$\'<\/dt><dd>Вставляет \"часть строки, которая следует за совпавшей подстрокой<\/dd><dt>$n или $nn, где <code>n/nn<\/code> - десятичные цифры<\/dt><dd>Вставляет n-ю скобку в совпадении, если первый аргумент - объект <code>RegExp<\/code><\/dd><\/dl>';
  
  str_spec = str_spec.replace(/\\/g,"")
  
  $('.no_spec').val(str_spec);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="no_spec"></textarea>
```

Просто с помощью регулярки удалили обратный слеш.

Comment: Спасибо, только мне нужно передать HTML код с двойными или одинарными кавычками.

Comment: @Alexander Goroshev сейчас тот момент то же добовлю в ответ, вам нужно что бы после возврата кода оно было без экранирования правильно?

Comment: Либо после возврата, либо при отправке. И нужно, чтоб все символы отправлялись. Сейчас, при попытке отправить одинарные кавычки вообще отправка обрывается

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev смотрите подойдет вторая часть ответа?

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev подошел ответ?

Comment: .replace на простом примере я бы без труда написал. Он не интегрируется в мой пример и проблема с отправкой одинарных кавычек никуда не ушла.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev В вопросе вы так написали 


Вопрос второй. Если все же избежать нельзя, то можно ли при выдаче данных пройтись по всему содержимому и убрать лишний символ, например, через .replace? Вот участки отвечающие за вывод данных:

Если вам нужно что то другое то обясните что хотите сделать и может сможем помочь

Comment: Исходя из второго варианта, вывод данных должен выглядеть вот так: `$('#others'+i).html(arr['o_field_' + i]).replace(/\\/g,"");`, однако, данная конструкция выводит все без изменений.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev то есть не убирает екранировку со строки?

Comment: Да, происходит вывод экранированной строки.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev как то не вериться, я проверил на разных браузерах и строки с экранированием когда выводишь на экран или в консоль то показывает браузер нормально (`без экранирования`). может подробный пример введете в вопрос?

Comment: С перебором простых строк через `.replace` нет. И ваш пример работает, однако при оборачивании выдачи результата, как я писал выше, результат не менялся. Данную и другие конструкции с replace я пробовал. В общем-то, потому и сюда обратился, так как не могу понять причин, почему результат выдается с экранированием. Так же было не понятно, почему не срабатывает stripslashes() в php для _POST или _GET. Но, в ответе ниже "костыль" оказался рабочим и данные отправляются в чистом виде.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev  если так необходимо то сделайте это перед отправкой формы `ajax` запросом.