# Почему в условиях можно не фильтрировать глобальные переменные?

Tags: mysql, post, get

Известно, что $_GET или $_POST параметры нужно фильтрировать при запросах mysql, иначе это считается уязвимостью sql inj, однако несовсем понятно, почему 
в условиях можно не фильтрировать глобальные переменные?

Например `if(isset($_GET['blabla'])){ // почему это не считается уязвимостью? }`

Comment: если используется PDO, а его давно завезли, то никаких sql injection не будет. А фильтровать и валидировать нужно все, что приходит от клиента.

Comment: А что такого пользователь может запихнуть в blabla, в результате чего в этой строчке случится что-то плохое?

Comment: Ну например какой нибудь php код который сначала закрывает условие и выполняет произвольный код, ведь в mysql же можно переделать запросы, но не понятно, почему многие люди не фильтрируют глобальные переменные в условиях.

Comment: Эм, и каким образом этот php код выполнится по-вашему?

Answer (score 1):

**Почему SQL-инъекции существуют**

Сразу же отмечу, что их не существует, если используется корректно настроенные mysqli или PDO с подготовленными выражениями, так как там всё экранируется автоматически. (В некорректно настроенные, например, с неправильной кодировкой, инъекция может просочиться; подробнее см. [Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637185))

Чаще всего SQL-инъекции появляются, когда вы собираете строку с SQL-запросом вручную и забываете что-нибудь экранировать. Так вот, когда вы пишете код вроде такого:

```
$user = $_GET['username'];
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
```

если в параметре `username` передать `0' UNION SELECT password FROM users;--`, то в итоге получается вот такая **строка**:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = '0' UNION SELECT password FROM users;--'
```

Эта строка как есть передаётся в mysql-сервер. Он эту строку **парсит** и выполняет всё, что в ней записано: он не знает происхождения этой строки, он не знает, что вы туда подставили параметр от пользователя. Всё, что ему остаётся, — это покорно выполнить всё, что его попросили, а его попросили выдать все пароли (хорошо, если они будут захэшированные с солью). Поэтому здесь получается инъекция.

---

**Почему код вида** `if(isset($_GET['blabla']))` **безопасен и не содержит инъекции**

В случае с php-кодом вместо строки у вас есть готовый **php-файл**. В этот php-файл не подставляется никаких параметров извне: никаких строк, как в случае с SQL-кодом выше, не собирается.

Ещё **перед** тем, как загрузить `$_GET` и `$_POST`, php-движок парсит php-файл и строит примерно такую последовательность инструкций (описываю условно, в реальном байткоде не ковырялся):

- достать из массива `$_GET` значение по ключу `'blabla'`
- вызвать функцию `isset`, передав ей первым аргументом значение из предыдущего шага, и получить возвращённое ей значение

[Функция isset просто сравнивает полученное значение с NULL и больше ничего не делает.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)

Только **после** того, как php-движок распарсит файл и составит такую инструкцию — только тогда будут загружены пользовательские данные и будет выполнен этот код.

Ни на одном этапе в данной инструкции содержимое `$_GET['blabla']` не интерпретируется как php-код, isset тоже не интерпретирует php-код, поэтому независимо от того, что пользователь запихнёт в GET-параметр `blabla` — этот код **всегда** будет безопасен.

---

**Когда же возможна php-инъекция?**

Когда в php-файле явно прописано интерпретировать значение как php-код. Например, с использованием `eval` или `assert`.

В общем, вам нужно знать, интерпретируют ли функции, которые вы вызываете, параметры как какой-то код или нет. Если нет, то, скорее всего, вы в безопасности. Код из переменных никогда не выполнится сам по себе.

Comment: Выражаюсь коряво и поэтому не хотел писать ответ, но нужно же как-то компенсировать откровенно плохой соседний ответ

Comment: Этт ответ правильный и его стоит принять галкой

Comment: `Сразу же отмечу, что их не существует, если используется mysqli или PDO с подготовленными выражениями, так как там всё экранируется автоматически.` - ну не совсем так.. **[Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482)** .... Но в целом, если настроить корректно, то можно вздохнуть с облегчением

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил в ответ на видном месте

Comment: @andreymal гоже)

Answer (score -1):

php code sniffer для WordPress в phpStorm требует применять к глобальным переменным $_GET или $_POST две функции: одну из семейства sanitize_xxx(), вторую - verify_nonce().

В семейство sanitize_xxx() входят: sanitize_email(), sanitize_key(), sanitize_text_field(), sanitize_title(). Они производят очистку входных данных, полученных по $_POST или $_GET.

verify_nonce производит проверку одноразового кода [nonce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce), чтобы предотвратить подделку запроса.

`isset($_GET['blabla'])` не является уязвимостью, потому что всего лишь проверяет, установлена глобальная переменная или нет. А вот код

```
$bla = $_GET['blabla']
```

будет отмечен php sniffer как недопустимый.

Comment: Что-то я не понял, как отфильтровывание всего кроме a-z0-9_- относится к данному вопросу?

Comment: Функция очищает строку, чтобы использовать её как ключ. Ключи используются как разные внутренние ID. Относится к данному вопросу впрямую, потому что code sniffer для phpStorm, полагаю, делали люди более опытные, чем мы тут.

Comment: Где в вопросе вообще упоминаются ключи? Я до сих пор не вижу абсолютно никакой связи между вопросом и ответом.

Comment: Эту фильтрацию code sniffer требует применять к **глобальным переменным**, полученным через $_GET или $_POST

Comment: Под глобальными переменными автор имеет в виду сами $_GET и $_POST, никаких новых глобальных переменных автор не создаёт и не использует. Пример кода же в вопросе есть. Продолжаю не видеть связи между вопросом и ответом

Comment: А значения таким образом фильтровать недопустимо, это вы уже должны и так понимать. А ключи в вопросе не упоминаются

Comment: Так фильтруют ключи, есть и другие функции для фильтрации. Вопрос называется "Почему в условиях можно не фильтрировать глобальные переменные?". Я отвечаю, что нельзя не фильтровать, по крайней мере, если хочешь, чтобы код соответствовал стандартам.

Comment: Рекомендую вам читать весь вопрос перед написанием ответа ;) В вопросе написано, цитирую буква в букву: `if(isset($_GET['blabla'])){ // почему это не считается уязвимостью? }` — в вашем ответе я не вижу ответа на этот вопрос (или опровержения, что это на самом деле уязвимо)

Comment: Вы опустили слово "например". Думаю, намеренно. Я дал ответ на весь вопрос, а не на один пример. Рекомендую вам не заниматься схоластикой, а подискутировать с создателями code sniffer.

Comment: Ну зато вы наконец-то ответили на вопрос хоть как-то :) Я уже почти собрался отправлять тревогу.

Comment: @andreymal да отправляйте хоть две. Я уже давно заметил - те, кто не способны ответить на вопрос хоть как-то, юродствуют в комментариях.

Comment: Это лучше, чем когда те, кто не способны ответить на вопрос, отвечают на вопрос ;)

Comment: @andreymal кто из нас способен отвечать на вопросы, показывает репутация

Comment: Скорее она просто показывает активность на сайте

Comment: @andreymal оставьте себе ваши самооправдания. Ваш удел - троллинг, а за него репутацию не начисляют.