# Почему PDO не экранирует кавычки?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `sell`.`themes` (`name`, `preview`, `them`, `price`, `create_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())';
$pdo->prepare($sql)
->execute(array($n['name'], $n['preview'], $n['them'], $n['price']));
```

Вот таким кодом вставляю  в базу новые записи, когда в значениях любой из переменной есть кавычки они без экранирования вставляются в базу, это нормально?

вот скрин из PMA

[image: скрин]

Comment: Да, нормально, любые данные в БД кладутся как есть. Было бы плохо, если бы вы положили в БД одно, а она потом вернула вам другое

Comment: @Mike но насколько я понимаю, таким образом можно провести sql inj атаку

Comment: @user254893 нельзя. Сейчас я попробую расписать подробно в ответе

Comment: @user254893 Нет, SQL атака была бы если бы вместо `?` подставили переменную, кавычка сломала бы запрос. А так кавычка как есть сядет в базу, вы точно так же как есть ее прочитаете. На запрос она никак повлиять не может. И кстати если бы вставляли в БД `insert ... ('abc\'')` т.е. нормально экранированные данные, то в БД бы значение лежало уже без обратной косой. Экранирование же нужно только на этапе компиляции запроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, видимо, не до конца понимаете, где и зачем нужно экранирование. Давайте разберём весь путь ваших данных от INSERT до вывода на экран в вашем браузере.

**Отправка SQL-запроса**

База данных должна уметь хранить произвольные данные, в том числе любые символы в любых строках. Но вот незадача — кавычки это спецсимволы в SQL. Если мы, возьмём, например, такую строку:

```
хорошие данные"), ("я хакер азаза"); --
```

и попытаемся её добавить через примерно такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("сюда подставляем строку")
```

то получится такой SQL-код:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("хорошие данные"), ("я хакер азаза"); -- ")
```

Да, это **SQL-инъекция**. Вместо одной исходной строки база данных запишет две: `хорошие данные` и `я хакер азаза`.

Но ведь запрещать кавычки для предотвращения инъекции это неудобно, мы же наверно хотим сохранить строку `хорошие данные"), ("я хакер азаза"); --` в базе данных как есть, чтобы пользователь её мог потом прочитать в точно таком же виде мог прочитать? (В конце концов, если бы все запрещали кавычки, я бы не смог написать этот ответ, в нём же много кавычек :)

К счастью, есть **экранирование**. Кавычки экранируются заменой `"` на `\"` (если в строке изначально есть обратный слэш `\`, то он тоже экранируется заменой на `\\`). С экранированием получается такой код:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("хорошие данные\"), (\"я хакер азаза\"); -- ")
```

Так вот, **PDO делает экранирование автоматически**. Если [всё сконфигурировано правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637185), SQL-инъекция в коде из вашего вопроса невозможна.

Но это не значит, что экранированные кавычки так и сохранятся! Когда база данных **парсит** этот SQL-запрос, она, как бы корректнее выразиться, в общем **автоматически убирает экранирование со строки**. Экранирование нужно только для того, чтобы при разборе SQL-запроса база данных не попутала кавычку внутри строки с кавычкой, означающей окончание строки. После разбора база данных уже ничто ни с чем не попутает и всё экранирование можно безопасно убрать, и строка `хорошие данные"), ("я хакер азаза"); --` в итоге сохраняется как есть. Здесь всё безопасно, база данных сама позаботится об этом, вам важно лишь экранировать строку перед подстановкой в SQL-запрос (повторюсь, PDO это делает автоматически, код из вопроса безопасен).

**PMA забирает строку из базы данных**

Перед отображением содержимого вам PMA делает запрос вроде `SELECT * FROM mytable` и в ответе получает нашу строку со всеми кавычками, сохранёнными в предыдущем шаге (как устроен протокол передачи строки от базы данных в PMA, я не знаю, но там тоже всё безопасно). Потом PMA должен запихнуть эту строку в HTML-код с красивой табличкой и передать его вам, чтобы браузер эту табличку нарисовал.

Но здесь уже становится возможно **XSS**. Это когда в строке оказывается что-то вроде `<script>alert("XSS!")</script>` — если запихнуть это в HTML-код как есть, то браузер это воспримет не как текст, а как HTML-тег, обозначающий скрипт, и выполнит любой код внутри него (а этот любой код сможет, например, передать злоумышленнику ваши логин и пароль от текущего сайта). Поэтому перед выводом PMA тоже всё **экранирует** с помощью HTML-сущностей.

Из строки

```
хорошие данные"), ("я хакер азаза"); --
```

получается

```
хорошие данные&quot;), (&quot;я хакер азаза&quot;); --
```

а из строки

```
<script>alert("XSS!")</script>
```

получается

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;XSS!&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

Если в исходной строке есть символ `&`, то он экранируется как `&amp;`. Если там уже есть `&amp;`, то с экранированием получается `&amp;amp;` ну и так далее :)

**Чтение HTML-кода браузером**

Сервер (PMA) отвечает браузеру HTML-кодом, в котором все спецсимволы в ваших строках вот так вот экранированы. Когда браузер читает это всё, он теперь воспринимает это не как теги, а как обычный текст, и опасности появления XSS нет. Но перед выводом на экран тоже убирает всё экранирование — заменяет `&quot;` обратно на `"` и так далее.

Поэтому вы в итоге видите не `fhfh\" OR 1` и не `fhfh\&quot; OR 1`, а  `fhfh" OR 1` — ровно такую строку, какую вы изначально и хотели отправить в базу данных.

Comment: P.S. Если вы откроете исходный HTML-код этой страницы, то увидите, что все спецсимволы в моём ответе экранированы :) https://i.imgur.com/8UNnACT.png (правда, кавычки не экранированы там, где их можно не экранировать, но, например, внутри значений атрибутов их экранировать нужно)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'sell'.'themes' ('name', 'preview', 'them', 'price', 'create_at') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())"; 
$pdo->prepare($sql) ->execute(array($n['name'], $n['preview'], $n['them'], $n['price']));
```

Категорически НЕЛЬЗЯ без ручного екранирования вставлять так кавычки, только так.

`$foo = "fuiyg 'ookjgi' lifuo";` - так можно

`$foo = 'fjokt "hkooy" ogupy "jkjf" gju';` и так можно

`$foo = 'lkgoo 'dgoov' kifg 'fik' jgu';` - так, и 
`$foo = "fynnfr "fgjiy" dhj "fhji" dgj";` - нельзя

Comment: А какое отношение имеет ваш ответ по экранированию кавычек в языке php к вопросу по БД ? У ТС нет в тексте констант с кавычками

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что значение $sql в вапросе правильно присвоено???

Comment: Да, абсолютно правильно. текст SQL в обычных апострофах, имена колонок внутри запроса в _обратных апострофах_

Comment: Я виноват, с телефона недосмотрел что кавычки разние, но ето все равно исправит проблему человека.

Comment: Не исправит, потому что никакой проблемы нет. кавычки содержатся у него в тексте внутри вставляемых переменных. в БД они ложатся как есть, что абсолютно правильно.

Comment: Исправит, так как обратные кавычки никак не обрабатываются а просто выставляются как обычный текст, а в данной ситуации он хотел заполнить таблицу, обратние кавычки не обработались и вставились как есть, если вставит как в моем ответе все пройдет успешно

Comment: Нет, обратные кавычки в БД не вставлялись. Обратные апострофы в тексте MySQL обозначают, что внутри них _имена_ колонок, а не текст. текст в MySQL заключается в обычные апострофы или двойные кавычки. В БД сели не эти кавычки, а содержащиеся _внутри_ переменных `$n['name']`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо 

Comment: @Mike, я правильно понимаю что вставляемые переменный можно не контролировать в плане кавычек? даже в такой ситуации - $n['name'] = $_POST['name'];

Comment: @user254893 `я правильно понимаю что вставляемые переменный можно не контролировать в плане кавычек?` - по сути да, но надо чуть-чуть знать некоторые нюансы и всё будет хорошо. смотри (читай) вопрос  [Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482)

Comment: @user254893 Да, используя плейсхолдеры `?` и передавая значения при execute никакой контроль не требуется

Comment: @Mike; @АлексейШиманский Спасибо