# PHP ошибка в синтаксисе PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте, добрые люди, помогите пожалуйста с pdo запросом, вот код

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE cat_id=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ? ');
$stmt->execute(array($get_cat, 1, 40));
```

выдает ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1' , '40'' at line 1' in ..........

А если делаю так:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE cat_id=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 , 40 ');
$stmt->execute(array($get_cat));
```

То все нормально. Я только учусь, не судите строго. Версия PHP 5.2

Comment: а не проще 1 и 40 сразу внести в запрос? если бы они были изменяемыми, то были написаны переменными.

Comment: @Jean-Claude предполагаю, что у ТС там итак переменные, просто он упростил это в вопросе

Comment: Да, вы правы Алексей, я упростил код, на самом деле у меня  подстановка переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить вкратце, то нужно в текущем запросе (а лучше вообще) выключить режим эмуляции подготавливаемых запросов.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Будет примерно так:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE cat_id=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ?";
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($get_cat, 1, 40));
$data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

Если по каким-то причинам эмуляция вам нужна, то скорее всего придется явно кастовать целочисленные значения к `(int)`

---

P.S. чтобы иметь представление о том, что можно включить или отключить можно посмотреть тут: [Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482)

Comment: Вроде работает, спасибо, ты настоящий друг. ))

Comment: отправил скромный донат.