# Если идёт селект только одной колонки, могу ли я не использовать fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, sql

Настрочил в горячке бредовый код, теперь сижу, исправляю. У меня есть запрос к бд:

```
$answer = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE id = ".$_GET["question"]);
```

И `answer` всегда получается `0`, не могу понять почему.

Вот я и подумал: можно ли отбросить `fetch_assoc`, если получаю только одно значение?

Comment: Не пишите в горячке бредовый код. Используйте подготовленные выражения (prepared statements). По теме полно информации в сети ([пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/213987), [пример2](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/344696/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [документации `mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

> Возвращаемые значения ¶
>
> Возвращает `FALSE` в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения
>   запросов `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` или `EXPLAIN` `mysqli_query()` вернет
>   объект `mysqli_result`. Для остальных успешных запросов `mysqli_query()`
>   вернет `TRUE`.

относительно вашего вопроса

> можно ли отбросить fetch_assoc, если получаю только одно значение?

Как видно из текста справки, данная функция возвращает объект `mysqli_result`. Далее из него надо получиьт данные, для чего испоьзуется функция `fetch*`, в переводе `fetch` означает *получить*, так что если в ваших планах есть получение строк результата  то от этой функции вам не деться никуда.

*зы: false там у вас возвращается а не 0*

Comment: Я уже догадался, спасибо.