# Выборка из MySQL драйвер PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, выборка

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать PDO Mysql. Столкнулся с таким вопросом, пишу файл личных страниц для пользователей, и делаю выборку из БД. Хотел уточнить, нужно ли фильтровать переменную $_GET['username'] или же достаточно прогнать через bindParam? Не получится ли SQL Inj?
Спасибо)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_GET['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `isset($_GET['username'])` как минимум нужен, чтобы убедиться, что переменная вообще есть в наличии.

Comment: Вот так подойдет?
$username = isset($_GET['username']);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php `if (! isset($_GET['username'])) {exit('Пошли на фиг! С новым годом!');}` в начале скрипта, который использует `$_GET['username']` P.S. Прежде чем использовать какие-то данные пришедшие со стороны, нужно проверить их наличии как минимум. Как максимум - прогнать через валидатор.

Comment: Ну а фильтрация нужна? В случае с $_GET['id'] нужна фильтрация intval($_GET['id'])

Comment: Инъекция исключена в любом случае. За это можете не беспокоится. Дополнительные проверки в общем то нужны только для того что бы запрос (или скрипт целиком) не завершился с ошибкой, а была возможность дать пользователю более вразумительное сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Почитайте ответы на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083