# добавление данных в базу

Tags: php, html, mysql

есть, множество встроенных функций в php  для фильтрации данных, о каждой из них можно найти такое же множество инфы в интернете, но я уже запутался, я просто хочу конкретно знать, какие средства защиты данных при ДОБАВЛЕНИИ В БАЗУ из форм можно использовать? я использую библиотеку PDO. Достаточно ли использовать только addslashes()?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как-то так, например:

```
function clean($value){
$value = trim($value);//убираем пробелы вначале и в конце
$value = strip_tags($value);//убираем html теги
$value = htmlspecialchars($value);//заменяем теги спецсимволами
return $value;
}
//чистим полученные данные
$_POST['value'] = clean($_POST['value']);
```