# Выводит ошибку Warning: mysqli_query() expects at most 3 parameters, 6 given почему?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'', 'test');
$a = $_GET['login'];
$b = $_GET['password'];
mysqli_query($mysql , 'INSERT INTO `registr` (`login`, `password`) VALUES (',$a,',',$b,')');
?>
```

Comment: потому что `,$a,`  а не `.$a.`

Comment: но данная синтаксическая проблема - самая маленькая неприятность из всего этого кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($mysql , 'INSERT INTO `registr` (`login`, `password`) VALUES (',$a,',',$b,')');
```

> `mysqli_query()` expects at most 3 parameters, 6 given почему?

Итого имеем:

```
mysqli_query(
```

1. `$mysql`
 2. `INSERT INTO registr (login, password) VALUES (`
 3. `$a`
 4.  `','`
 5. `$b`
 6. `')'`

```
)
```

Настоятельно рекомендуется использовать [биндинг параметров с подготовленными выражениями для передачи параметров в запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/223826), а также не использовать `GET`-запросы для изменения (вставки/редактирования/удаления) данных

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($mysql , 'INSERT INTO `registr` (`login`, `password`) VALUES ('.$a.','.$b.')');
```

Конкатенация строки в PHP происходит при помощи точки, у вас - запятые.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'','test');

$a = $_GET['login'];
$b = $_GET['password'];

$query = mysqli_prepare($mysql , "INSERT INTO `registr` (`login`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ss', $a, $b);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

Рекомендую вам в дальнейшем использовать подготовленные запросы таких драйверов как `PDO`, иначе вашей базай будут пользоваться все кто хотят.

Comment: вы там чего фетчить собрались из `insert` запроса?

Comment: Оу, да, спасибо.

Comment: а что такое `'h', 's'` ? почему вообще там две строки, и что такое `h` ?

Comment: @teran, ещё одна ошибка, благодарю. :)