# Помощь с вводом данных в бд через форму

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

```html
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$database = "i_love_books";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
echo "Connected successfully";
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO books (photo, name, author, year, label, krat) VALUES ('$photo','$name','$author','$year','$label','$krat')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>1</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
  <input name="author" type="text" placeholder="Avtor"/>
  <input name="photo" type="text" placeholder="photo"/>
  <input name="label" type="text" placeholder="izdatelstvo"/>
  <input name="krat" type="text" placeholder="krat"/>
  <input name="year" type="text" placeholder="god"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вводимые данные не заносятся в соответствующие поля в БД на phpmyadmin. Добавляется строка без значений.

Comment: а где $name=$_POST['name'] итд

Comment: а зочем это нужно и как она работает скажите плиз?

Comment: Вы если пишите на php, хотя бы смотрите примеры на https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: а как в переменную $name данные заносите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$database = "i_love_books";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";
if(count($_POST)>0){
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val ){
        $$key = $val;
    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO books (`photo`, `name`, `author`, `year`, `label`, `krat`) VALUES ('$photo','$name','$author','$year','$label','$krat')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>1</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
  <input name="author" type="text" placeholder="Avtor"/>
  <input name="photo" type="text" placeholder="photo"/>
  <input name="label" type="text" placeholder="izdatelstvo"/>
  <input name="krat" type="text" placeholder="krat"/>
  <input name="year" type="text" placeholder="god"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

так дольжно работать!

Вывести данные из базу данных

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `books`";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo $row['name'];
echo $row['photo'];
echo $row['autor'];

}}
```

Таким образом будет вывести данные из бд

Comment: Здравствуйте! К сожалению,  ваш код does not work.

Comment: Поправил сейчас попробуйте

Comment: Ого. Спасибо большое. Выручил, друг.

Comment: Еще один вопрос, друг. Как вывести все данные на страницу? Подскажи, если не затруднит.

Comment: Отвечу за отдельной коментарии

Comment: Какой комментарий?

Comment: Изменил мой ответ там и добавил возможност вывести данные из бд

Comment: Спасибо, ты реально делаешь помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
$photo','$name','$author','$year','$label','$krat'
```

А где вы получаете эти переменные с поста?
[Variables From External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

вы указываете у формы способ отправки POST, данные после отправки находятся в глобальном массиве $_POST. Перед тем как использовать переменную (типа $name), ее нужно определить. В вашем случае взять данные с поста.

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
```

2й вариант получения:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде отсутствуют у переменных $photo, $name, $author, $year, $label, $krat отсутствует значение.
Код:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

присваивает переменной значение, полученное из ассоциативного массива _POST, в который отправляются все данные, посланные методом POST из ваших HTML форм.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю еще стоит защитить свою базу данных от недоброжелателей, пример можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637185/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-sql-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)