# не получается отправить подготовленный запрос в базу. DESC LIMIT ?, 10

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Пытаюсь сделать выборку из базы. С другими запросами на аналогичных функциях все работает отлично. А этот выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Делаю так:

```
public function get_comments($position) {

    $query_str = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, 10";
    $params_arr = array($position);
    $connection = $this->connect->start();
    $query = $connection->prepare($query_str);
    $query->execute($params_arr);

    var_dump($query);
}
```

В итоге - Syntax error ..... for the right syntax to use near ''1', 10' at line 1. То-есть как будто эту стартовую позицию запрос оборачивает в какие-то кавычки и поэтому ошибка синтаксиса. Но в других запросах постоянно так писал и проблем не было. пытался приводить число в переменной к числовому типу. Бесполезно. Как только рукой сам вписываю число в запрос - сразу начинает работать нормально. Но мне нужно именно подготовить это число...

Comment: Большинство БД не позволяют использовать подстановку переменных в limit через подготовленные выражения. Сделайте проверку, что $position число и явно подставляйте ее в текст запроса.

Comment: хотя помню кто то тут писал в подобном вопросе, что можно перевести драйвер PDO в режим где он подстановку не средствами БД делает, тогда будет работать и текущий вариант. Но кто и где это писал я сейчас не найду

Comment: то-есть через конкатенацию строк собрать строку запроса и вставить туда переменную?

Comment: @Mike эмуляция подготовки в pdo есть. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497675/223826

Comment: `"... limit $position, 10"`

Comment: все, понял, спасибо большое!!

Comment: если посмотрите на документацию к [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php) то там написано, что массив параметров принимается, как строковые значения: _" `input_parameters`     Массив значений, содержащий столько элементов, сколько параметров заявлено в SQL-запросе. Все значения будут приняты, как имеющие тип `PDO::PARAM_STR`. "_. Чтобы явно тип данных указать, надо `bindParam` делать

Comment: @MoloF речь про PDO а не mysqli

Comment: @teran плохо прочёл вопрос, по коду не отличил от обычного `stmt` , моя ошибка

Comment: @Mike это как надо искать чтобы по запросу pdo limit не увидеть первый результат в гугле?